# ¿Existe alguna manera de modificar el estilo de la pagina de "Index of" de un servidor?

Tags: css

[image: ejemplo]
Por ejemplo, al acceder a la la raíz de una directorio que contiene o no ficheros y mas directorios. He buscado por CSS pero no he visto nada.
Alguna idea? Es siquiera posible?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Este tutorial puede ayudarte bastante https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/ detalla sobre como modificarlo en Apache.

Muy brevemente, si quisieras agregar características ya existentes de Apache al navegador de directorios vas a tener que modificar la directiva de `IndexOptions`, la lista completa de opciones se encuentra aquí: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions

Un ejemplo es lo siguiente:

```
# COLOCAR INDEX OPTIONS
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst
```

FancyIndexing - Muestra información adicional del archivo.

IgnoreCase - Ordena alfabéticamente sin importar las mayúsculas o minúsculas.

FoldersFirst - (Esta opción solo hace efecto si FancyIndexing está activado) Muestra primero los subdirectorios y luego los archivos que están en el directorio.

Y hay muchos más que puedes utilizar, ahora vamos a personalizar a tu gusto el código HTML. Primero debes saber que hay 3 módulos que conforman esa página:

- El Header — por defecto es generado automáticamente por Apache.
- El listado del directorio - forzosamente Apache lo genera, no se puede modificar.
- El Footer - también llamado como "Readme".

Afortunadamente Apache permite sobreescribir la ruta del archivo header y footer, que podrás modificar con tu código html. Deberás agregar el siguiente código al archivo .htaccess (recuerda tener habilitado esto en la configuración):

```
# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName header.html

# SPECIFY FOOTER FILE
ReadmeName footer.html
```

Y en cada directorio deberás colocar los archivos header.html y footer.html. Y para que no se muestren en el listado deberás agregar lo siguiente a la configuración de Apache o editando el archivo .htaccess:

```
# Ignorará los archivos en el listado del directorio
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html
```

Lo demás está incluido en la guía simplemente es editar eso y podrás personalizarlo, aunque no totalmente, pero si en su mayor parte.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, exactamente lo que necesitaba!